# 'fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND' - node.js mysql lambda

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write a node.js lambda function which will connect to a database within a MYSQL RDS instance in AWS and pull down some sample records, but I am getting the above error.

I have created the RDS to be publicly accessible and have also created the lambda method under the same VPC as the RDS. The code I am using is below:

```
var mysql=require('mysql'); //Require whatever connector you need.

//console.log("beware of ", beware);
var beware=1;  //This is declared outside the handler: it is possible that its last value will be reused when we enter the function again.

//This function will return a connection. Notice that it's declared outside
//the handler, thus inside the container. It may be reused but I don't think
//that matters because it is self-contained.

function getConnectionCred()
{
    var params={
        host     : '(myconnname).amazonaws.com:3306',
        user     : 'username',
        password : 'password',
        database: 'database'};

    return mysql.createConnection(params);
}

//This is your handler.
exports.handler=function(event, context)
{
    //This is declared inside the handler: it is guaranteed to never be reused!.
    var connection=getConnectionCred();

    var del = connection._protocol._delegateError;
connection._protocol._delegateError = function(err, sequence){
  if (err.fatal) {
    console.trace('fatal error: ' + err.message);
  }
  return del.call(this, err, sequence);
};

    //Do things with your connection.
    var query_string='SELECT * from table';

    connection.query(query_string, [beware], function(res, err){

        //Check for errors, disconnect and exit with failure.
        if(err){
            console.log("Query failed", err);
            connection.end(function(err){
                context.fail(0);
            });
        }
        //Disconnect and exit with success.
        else{
            connection.end(function(err){

                if(err){
                    console.log("Warning: disconnection failed" + err);
                }

                context.succeed(res);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction of getting this error resolved that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have specified host with port number at the end:

```
host: '(myconnname).amazonaws.com:3306'
```

Remove `:3306`.

Comment: Hi,  I have tried the above and received the following error: https://pastebin.com/BZ4VyAeS

Comment: So this is a very different error then. Check if lambda has access to the DB host.

Comment: Hi, the Lambda function is created under the same VPC and security group as the RDS - is there any other configuration I would need to do?

Comment: @CallumHolden You need to mark this as the correct answer; the error you received afterwards is due to something else. That said, that other error you received is usually due to VPC/security group issues. Triple-check those; being in the same security group isn't enough. The security group also needs to allow traffic from your lambda function to the MySQL instance